# Use another image for the dummy camera

Tags: android, genymotion

How can I use another image (instead of the Genymotion logo) on the Genymotion virtual device? I would like to test my application on various types of images.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want the camera to display an image, not just download an image to the device. ie that I can simulate what the camera sees. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Genymotion doesn't have this feature yet, and I don't think there is a way to hack around it.

Disclaimer: I work for Genymotion.